# Comparing Images for similarity

Tags: opencv

I want to compare two images (number plate images). I already separated each character from number plate using ROI command. Now, I want to compare this with the stored templates or characters to recognize the character. I want to know how to compare their similarity.I am new to openCV. I am using the standard number plates.

Comment: Use the search box, I've seen this question asked and answered many times.

Answer (score 1):

Opencv implements the template matching function. Here is the prototype:

```
void matchTemplate(const Mat& image, const Mat& templ, Mat& result, int method);
```

Methods of comparison are mostly based on sum of squared differences with differents normalization terms.
In case of colored images each sum in the denominator is done over all of the channels (and separate mean values are used for each channel).
Use the OpenCV function minMaxLoc to find the maximum and minimum values.

Answer (score 1):

try cvMatchTemplate

void cvMatchTemplate(const CvArr* image, const CvArr* templ, CvArr* result, int method);

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/object_detection.html