# Comparing Contours

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I have two similar images, one is the template and the other image is pictured through a camera (thus, subject to rotation and skew). I need to match the contour of the template image and the photographed image. Is the matchShape function of opencv sufficient? My concern is that if there are 2 circles on the image, they might have the same contour. Should I consider the position of the contours?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355015/how-to-compare-two-contours-of-a-binary-pattern-image/16365446#16365446

Answer (score 1):

In most cases [matchShapes()](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#matchShapes) method should work, because it uses [Hue moments](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#HuMoments) which are invariant to scale, rotation and reflection (Except 7th).

On the other hand if you need something more specific, you should devise your own error minimization problem just like the ones used in deformable templates. Examples of using deformable templates can be found in [my thesis](http://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CE0QFjAA&url=http://etd.lib.metu.edu.tr/upload/1224674/index.pdf&ei=DxW1T-y5MYvT4QTW4tidDg&usg=AFQjCNF-02lNnoFtHr5FQUS4ZSQCjKFvtw&sig2=C838iojWpqMCyLCkNr_AHg).

Comment: thanks! I just like to ask if I have 2 circles (same size) on the image, will it detect the correct circle?

Comment: If the position of the circle is important for you, you should check that seperately. matchShapes() should be invariant to the position of the circle.

Comment: do you know any algorithm to do that? I have to base the position on template image. thank you again for your reply

Comment: Can you post a sample image, and template please.